# How to send CTRL+C to a VPS through JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

I was wondering how I can send CTRL+C to my VPS by pressing a key such as **V**.

This is the code that I currently have for my userscript (tampermonkey):

```
       break;
        case 86:
            socket.emit("cmd", {
        "stop": "^C"
```

Currently, When the key **V** is pressed, it sends this line of text to my console :

> { stop: '^C' }

I want it to only send **^C** (which is CTRL+C) so it will stop my script. is there a way I can do this? thanks!

**EDIT**
 i also have another `.js` file that connects to the userscript, and can send data that way!

Comment: I am not certain this is possible. Regardless, it'd probably be better to just find out the pid of your script and then just `kill` it via the pid.

Comment: ok thanks, i will keep on the watch for more options!

Answer (score 0):

How you connect with your VPS? By PUTTY or bash shell? If yes, there is shortcut ctrl + shift + c to copy resource.

Comment: i am actually trying to stop the script. the shortcut CTRL+C will stop my .js window in PUTTY